# Will errorWithoutStackTrace be faster than error when there isn't HasCallStack?

Tags: performance, haskell

I noticed that the base package use `errorWithoutStackTrace` to implement lots of functions. Is there some performance different between the following two definition?

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:_) = x
head [] = errorWithoutStackTrace ("Prelude.head: empty list")

head :: [a] -> a
head (x:_) = x
head [] = withFrozenCallStack $ error ("Prelude.head: empty list")
```

Comment: Have you considered benchmarking it

Comment: @Li-yaoXia  https://gist.github.com/luochen1990/5062732c98c220d986adab5e4df6a252  I tested the normal branch, but don't know how to benchmark the error branch, since I cannot repeat to cause the error to make the difference significant.

Comment: You can evaluate values with `evaluate` and catch exceptions with `catch` (from `Control.Exception`).

Answer (score 2):

`error` means something bad happened so for most, if not all purposes, it does not matter how fast it is, because it indicates a program that's *not working*.

---

That said, a quick glance at the code is enough to reasonably guess that `error` does strictly more work than `errorWithoutStackTrace` (and that is compounded by the addition of `withFrozenCallStack` to the `error` variant of your code). Confirming that with benchmarks is left as an exercise to the reader.

Here's the definition of `error` and `errorWithoutStackTrace`:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Err.html#error

```
error s = raise# (errorCallWithCallStackException s ?callStack)

errorWithoutStackTrace s = raise# (errorCallException s)
```

Now those two internal functions are defined as follows:

```
errorCallException :: String -> SomeException
errorCallException s = toException (ErrorCall s)

errorCallWithCallStackException :: String -> CallStack -> SomeException
errorCallWithCallStackException s stk = unsafeDupablePerformIO $ do
  ...
  return $ toException (ErrorCallWithLocation s stack)
```

Note that both essentially do `toException (something s)`, but `errorCallWithCallStackException` also has a whole lot more code to handle the stack (in "`...`").